# Is the action on $L^2$ arising from a measure preserving action continuous?

Tags: analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a locally compact topological group, $X, \mu$ a probability space, and  $G\times X \rightarrow X$ a measurable group action which preserves $\mu$ (i.e. $\mu (gA)=\mu(A)$) . Does it follow that for any $f(x)\in L^2(X)$, the map $$G \rightarrow L^2(X), g \mapsto f(gx)$$ is continuous?

I'm sure it suffices to prove that $\mu (A \Delta g_nA) \rightarrow 0$ whenever $g_n \rightarrow e$ (where $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference) but I don't even see how to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would like to believe this to be true in the stated generality and it is often asserted either without proof or accompanied with some fervent hand-waving involving the name Fubini. Detailed and *correct* proofs are quite hard to find.

One good source is Lemme A.1.1 of Babillot et al, [Theoremes ergodiques pour les actions de groupes](http://www.univ-orleans.fr/mapmo/seminaires/nevo/livredraft.pdf). They do assume in the proof that $X$ is a *[standard Borel space](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Standard_Borel_space)*, that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite and $G$-invariant and that $G$ is second countable. They prove that the representation of $G$ on $L^p(X,\mu)$ is strongly continuous for $1 \leq p < \infty$.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it was asserted in the book "ergodic theory and topological dynamics of group actions on homogeneous spaces."